# How can I shim a jQuery plugin with JSPM?

Tags: jquery, systemjs, jspm

Moving an existing project to jspm, I have a few custom jQuery plugins, e.g.

```
//  path/to/mycustomplugin.js

$.fn.myCustomPlugin = function (options) {
   //something here
};
```

That is, it's not registered with jspm in any way. I thought I'd be able to add a shim:

```
// config.js
shim: {
  "packages": {
      "customplugin": {
          "main": "customplugin",
          "format": "global",
          "deps": ["jquery"],
          "exports": "$.myCustomPlugin"
      }
   }
},
map : {
   "customplugin" : "path/to/mycustomplugin"
}
```

And then import in the application:

```
import customplugin from "customplugin"
```

It doesn't work though - the file is never loaded, and

```
$(element).myCustomPlugin()
```

Is undefined. Documentation on this is hard to find.

Comment: do you have a working code to show ? I am also trying to import a third party Jquery plugin from github using JSPM, its loading the lib fine , but not calling the methods. No console errors though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a wrong shim. Try the following:

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@^2.2.0",
      (...)
    },
    "shim": {
      "custom-jquery": {
        "deps": ["jquery"],
        "exports": "$"
      }
    },
    (...)
  }
}
```

Moreover, in your custom plugin, don't forget to import query:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$.fn.myCustomPlugin = function (options) {
  //something here
};
```